# How to get latitude and longitude using a background service in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, service, latitude-longitude

I want to get the latitude and longitude of the user using a background service.I am using the following code to get the latitude and longitude in android.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 10;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0;

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public SharedPreferences pref;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Double latitude, longitude;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }


    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Log.d("LATLANG : ", latitude + " " + longitude);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I am calling the service from my activity using the following code:

```
Intent start_intent = new Intent(DaLoginActivity.this, MyService.class);
                    startService(start_intent);
```

This is where I call GPSTracker inside MyService:-

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        gps.getLatitude(); // returns latitude
        gps.getLongitude();

    }
Toast.makeText(gps, "Latitude : "+gps.getLatitude()+" "+gps.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return START_STICKY;
```

}

I am unable to get the latitude and longitude.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Use `FusedLocationApi`

Comment: Ok I am trying FusedLocationApi. But @Piyush I want to get the latitude and longitude in a background service.

Comment: Check [this](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918675/android-location-service-didnt-work-in-background)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code...

```
public class RTGPSLocationService extends Service {
    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 5000; // in Milliseconds
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    private final String TAG = "RTGPSLocationService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RTLog.d(TAG, "GPS Service created ...");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        RTLog.d("RTGPSLocationService", " " + isGPSEnabled + " " + isNetworkEnabled);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            RTLog.d(TAG, "Location Permission is declined");
        } else {
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            } else if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                callLocationDetailAPI(location);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        RTLog.d(TAG, "GPS Service destroyed ...");
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format("New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
            RTLog.d(TAG, location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
            RTLog.d(TAG, message);
            callLocationDetailAPI(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the service class you need to call from the MainActivity class.
I've used Fused Location Provider which is recommended to get location updates:-

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

Intent intent;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
String lat, lon;
public static String str_receiver = "servicetutorial.service.receiver";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("Service started Getting", "started!!!!!!!!!!");

    super.onCreate();
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    intent = new Intent(str_receiver);

}

synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("Connected:Getting ", "LOcation!!!!!!!!!!");
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
   /* if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

    }*/

    //use if you want location update

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    Log.d("LocationUpdatesRequest", "Granted");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        lon = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());

        intent.putExtra("latutide",mLastLocation.getLatitude()+"");
        intent.putExtra("longitude",mLastLocation.getLongitude()+"");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        Log.d("Latitue!!!!",lat);
        Log.d("Longitude!!!!",lon);

    }
    else{
        Log.d("Failed","Connection");
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

/*@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}*/

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    String msg = "Updated Location: " +
            Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("changed","after 30");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

Call the service from the main activity now:-

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationService.class));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,"started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And add the broadcast receiver in the MainActivity:-

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,"Broadcast receinved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        latitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("latutide"));
        longitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("longitude"));

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try { addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
            area.setText(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
            tv_locality.setText(stateName);
            tv_address.setText(countryName); }
        catch (IOException e1)
        { e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        tv_latitude.setText(latitude+"");
        tv_longitude.setText(longitude+"");
        tv_address.getText();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get updates in main thread using

```
locateme = new GPSTracker(Home.this);

if(locateme.canGetLocation()) {
     final double latitude = locateme.getLatitude();
     final double longitude = locateme.getLongitude();
     final float spd = locateme.getSpeed();
}
```

By this background tread service

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context context;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    float spd;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;


                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                spd = location.getSpeed();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {


                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return null;
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                            if (location != null) {

                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                spd = location.getSpeed();
                            }
                        }



                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {

            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    public float getSpeed() {
        if(location != null) {
            spd = location.getSpeed();
        }

        return spd;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```